# jquery - replace spans with input fields

Tags: jquery

so I have number of SPANs elements, and each one have input field.
 when I click SAVE button I would that the input field data will replace the SPAN data (according to the right div box- 1 or 2).

```
<a href="#" id="save-edit-button" data-attr="box2">SAVE</a>

<div id="box1-edit-area" >
    <li><span id="website" class="edit-text" style="display: inline; ">www.site.com</span>
        <input type="text" value="www.site.com" class="edit-input" id="website_input" >
    </li>

    <li><span id="first" class="edit-text" style="display: inline; ">first name</span>
        <input type="text" value="Roi" class="edit-input" id="first_input" >
    </li>
</div>  

<div id="box2-edit-area" >
    <li><span id="phone" class="edit-text" style="display: inline; ">97542668</span>
        <input type="text" value="97542668m" class="edit-input" id="phone_input" >
    </li>

    <li><span id="city" class="edit-text" style="display: inline; ">Paris</span>
        <input type="text" value="Paris" class="edit-input" id="city_input" >
    </li>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('click', "#save-edit-button", function ()
    {
        DATA INSIDE THE INPUT FIELD SHOULD REPLACE THE RELEVANT SPAN
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is a not "write code for me" service

Comment: agree with @u_mulder!

Comment: @u_mulder, can you give the to logic direction of how it should be done?

Comment: Get value from `input`. Set `span` html/text with this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#save-edit-button").click(function() {
  $("#box1-edit-area li input[type=text]").each(function() {
    $(this).prev().text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Use the above code, to see it working.

**what's happening here!**

use of click event on `$("#save-edit-button")`.

loops all the `input[type=text] within li`, checks the prev tag and adds the value of the current `input[text]` under it.

Comment: thanks! but i have 1 questions:  how do you refer to the right div box? I want to edit only the data within the right box (see data-attr="box2" )

Comment: just check my edited answer @roi, i have just added a parent referring id, here i cannot find out, which is right and left. so consider the id here to target the child elements of it.